# Multiple Like buttons with the same url

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, responsive-design

At the moment I'm creating a responsive web site so that it works on mobile devices as well.

The design is of such a nature that I hide a vertical menu that also contains a facebook like button when the screen width is less than 480px.

When the width is less than 480px I then display a horizontal menu (that was hidden) that also includes a Facebook Like button for the same page.

In other words, when screen width is greater than 480px then a vertical menu is displayed and the horizontal menu is hidden. When width is less than 480px the vertical menu is hidden and the horizontal menu is displayed.

The above scenario means that there will be 2 Facebook Like buttons on the same page with the same URL set.

Will this create problems?

Comment: No it shouldn't .Have you tried it yet?

Comment: What kind of problems were you expecting? If you only ever see one Like button at a time then what exactly would be the issue?

Comment: why making 2 menus? Give the vertical menu the design of the horizontal menu under 480px.

Comment: Just use one menu and use media queries to only load the css you need

Comment: It's a tricky design that will just solve a lot of problems having two menus. The problem I might be expecting is that perhaps Facebook has some kind of hangup or reason why it won't like multiple Facebook like buttons on the same page with the same URL. Perhaps they would see it as cheating or something like that and not record the likes or stop recording the likes.